# using more than once numpy.polyfit()?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

can i use more than once polyfit function on a curve in python; So if it is possible, can u explain ?  and also without split the curve ?

```
for i in range(1, 10,1):
    self.data1.append(self.a_0[i])
    self.t1.append(self.t_1[i])
for j in range (10, 20 ,1):
    self.data2.append(self.a_1[i])
    self.t2.append(self.t_2[i])
```